# How to achieve a smooth font-size change on window resize?

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-ui, plugins

How to achieve a smooth font-size change on window resize? with css or jquery.

Answer (score 2):

You can use CSS transitions, and a bit of jQuery.

**CSS:**

```
p{
    font-size: 14px;
    transition: font 1s;
}
```

**JavaScript (jQuery):**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(window).resize(function(){
        $('p').css('font-size', '25px');
    });
});
```

**FIDDLE:** https://jsfiddle.net/lmgonzalves/s1dL3c1y/